# TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, canvas, typeerror

I'm a beginner at this and haven't really done any JavaScript before so I hope you can help me. I've made a canvas that lets the user choose a shape and a colour with radio buttons which is then drawn on to the canvas. I've also added a checkbox with an option of adding a gradient to the chosen colour. Here's the program:
http://people.dsv.su.se/~caak1743/Canvas/canvas.html

Now I wan't to make it so that the shapes can be dragged and dropped around the canvas area. And I've found a code that I think can be altered to work on my program but I keep getting: 
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null 
init
(anonymous function) for the line:

```
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

and I have no idea what is wrong or how I can solve it. I've tried looking for similar programs with similar problems but haven't found anything that I can apply here. Here's the  code that I'm trying to incorporate with mine:

```
    function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
    }

    function draw() {
    clear();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
    rectangle(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
    rectangle();
    }

    function myMove(e){
    if (dragok){
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    }
    }

    function myDown(e){
    if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
    canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
    e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop){
    x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    dragok = true;
    canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
    }
    }

    function myUp(){
    dragok = false;
    canvas.onmousemove = null;
    }

    init();
    canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
    canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
```

Answer (score 17):

Just correct it to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onLoad=function(){ init();};
  function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
  }

  function draw() {
    clear();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FAF7F8";
    rectangle(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
    rectangle();
  }

  function myMove(e) {
    if (dragok) {
      x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
    }
  }

  function myDown(e) {
    if (e.pageX < x + 15 + canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageX > x - 15 +
        canvas.offsetLeft && e.pageY < y + 15 + canvas.offsetTop &&
        e.pageY > y -15 + canvas.offsetTop) {
      x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
      y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
      dragok = true;
      canvas.onmousemove = myMove;
    }
  }

  function myUp() {
    dragok = false;
    canvas.onmousemove = null;
  }

  init();
  canvas.onmousedown = myDown;
  canvas.onmouseup = myUp;
</script>
```

This should work. The problem is canvas element need to be ready to run the script. Since the `<script>` in `<head>` section runs before loading the `<canvas>` it gives the error.

Comment: Hello Mr@meetar can  i use canvas in React native

Answer (score 3):

I found two solutions. The first is to add jquery to you page and then there is no need for using in-html js by wrapping the whole js code into

`$(document).ready(function() { Your code here });`

what makes code run after html is ready, or just simply swapping head and body, where there is no need for using in-html js *(it executes the html earlier than js)*. These should work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do to that to get rid of the error.
Just add the canvas before the script and always place your script at the end.

```
<body>
<canvas id="ca"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var ca = document.getElementById("ca");
    var co = ca.getContext("2d");

// whatever your code    
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your script is ***AFTER*** your canvas element.