# javascript blurring function error

Tags: javascript, blur

I have changed a little bit in a javascript regarding blurring of canvas image. But somehow there is an error in the code. I can't seem to find it.. The code is this one: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlur.js and as you can see here, this is my changes to make it fit my needs. Hopefully you can see what I doing with it.

I don't know the problem but the browser console log says:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null`

And the line they are refering to is this one:

```
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

in both the blur function no matter if I am using RGB or RGBA

This is my changes t the first function you'll find in the original script from the link.

```
 function stackBlurImage( imgURL, canvasID, radius, blurAlphaChannel )
{
    var img = new Image();

    if (canvasID == "") {
        canvasID = "tempCanvas";
    }

    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        canvas.id = canvasID;

        var w = img.naturalWidth;
        var h = img.naturalHeight;

        canvas.style.width  = w + "px";
        canvas.style.height = h + "px";
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;

        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect( 0, 0, w, h );
        context.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );

        if ( isNaN(radius) || radius < 1 ) return;

        if ( blurAlphaChannel )
            stackBlurCanvasRGBA( canvasID, 0, 0, w, h, radius );
        else 
            stackBlurCanvasRGB( canvasID, 0, 0, w, h, radius );

    };
    img.src = imgURL;
```

Also I should mention that in the end of both `stackBlurCanvasRGBA` and `stackBlurCanvasRGB` function I have added this `setBlurredImage(id);` and also created this function:

```
function setBlurredImage(canvasID) {
    var canvas  = document.getElementById( canvasID );
    var image = document.getElementById( 'background' );
    var dataURI = canvas.toDataUrl("image/png");
    el.style.background = "url(" + dataURI + ")";
}
```

This is made because I don't want the canvas to be the background image of my webpage, also this makes it easier for me to CSS manipulate the background.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I saw this error a long time ago and there was a post to fix it here:

[TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null (anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660150/typeerror-cannot-call-method-getcontext-of-null-anonymous-function)

Let me know if this helps you out or if you have any questions about it.